# How to add two spaces at the end of lines that match two different strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace, markdown

I'm writing a bash script and I'd like to add two spaces at the end of lines matching two different strings in a file, maybe with sed or awk.

Here is a part of my file

```
### La justice européenne consacre le principe de neutralité du Net
Pour la première fois, une décision de justice a tranché : un fournisseur d'accès à Internet ne peut privilégier certains services ou applications au détriment d'autres. 
https://www.01net.com/actualites/la-justice-europeenne-consacre-le-principe-de-neutralite-du-net-1976661.html
Source : 01net

### La RRH 5G Open Source de Rapid.Space a convaincu Deutsche Telekom
L'entreprise française Rapid.Space est arriveé en tête du programme Telecom Infra Project (TIP) dans la catégorie des réseaux d'accès radio virtualisés (vRAN). Une victoire de plus pour l'open source.
https://www.toolinux.com/%3Fla-rrh-5g-open-source-de-rapid-space-a-convaincu-deutsche-telekom
Source : TOOLinux

### iOS 14 : faire de Firefox votre navigateur par défaut
La sortie du système d'exploitation iOS d'Apple ce mercredi donne une nouvelle possibilité aux utilisateurs de Firefox. En faire leur navigateur par défaut. Voici comment ça marche.
https://www.toolinux.com/%3Fios-14-faire-de-firefox-votre-navigateur-par-defaut
Source : TOOLinux

### Doctorant·e·s, bienvenue en science ouverte !
Vous êtes en début de thèse et apprenti·e chercheur·e ? Vous avez entendu parler de la science ouverte mais n'avez pas encore passé sa frontière ou tout juste commencé à explorer ses territoires ? Le Passeport pour la science ouverte est le guide conçu pour vous accompagner à chaque étape, du début de votre recherche à la diffusion de vos résultats !
https://www.ouvrirlascience.fr/doctorant%c2%b7e%c2%b7s-bienvenue-en-science-ouverte/
Source : Ouvrir la Science

### Liiibre, une solution complète pour vos projets collaboratifs
Hier, mardi 15 septembre, les copains et copines de Indie Hosters (structure membre du Collectif des Hébergeurs Alternatifs Transparents Ouverts Neutres et Solidaires) ont officiellement mis en ligne leur nouvelle solution&#160;: Liiibre. Iels nous avaient parlé de ce projet pendant la période de confinement et au sein de Framasoft, on les avait encouragé⋅es dans cette voie. En effet, chez Framasoft, nous  accompagnons depuis plusieurs années
https://framablog.org/2020/09/16/liiibre-une-solution-complete-pour-vos-projets-collaboratifs/
Source : Framablog
```

I want to add two spaces when the line does **not** begin with "###" or "Source".

This is a simple text file I want to convert to markdown, that's why I need to add two spaces for line breaks.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Show what you have tried already.

Comment: Good that you have mentioned you have tried few things. Kindly do add them in your question as it's highly encouraged on SO, cheers.

Comment: I didn't keep any record of what I tried precisely (as I see comments I'll do it next time) but the strategy was : find lines that doesn't begin with some strings and add two spaces / find the line beginning with some string and add spaces at the end of the next two lines / add two spaces at the end of each line and delete two spaces when the line begin with some string / add different dummy chars at the end of lines and replace it with two spaces... I tried with grep, awk and sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^###\|^Source/!s/$/  /' file
```

If the line does not start with `###` or `Source` add two spaces to the end of the line.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for ! I made a little modification to avoid adding two spaces on blank lines `sed -i '/^###\|^$\|^Source/!s/$/  /' file`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!/^#/ && !/source/{print $0,"","";next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** simply looking for lines which are not starting with # and printing line with 2 spaces at last, next will skip going to `1`(which is `awk`sh way to print current lines) if any line does start with # then it will simply print it.

***2nd solution:*** Using `printf`:

```
awk '!/^#/ && !/source/{printf("%s  \n",$0);next} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk will add two spaces at the end, but if there are already spaces it will replace them with two.

```
$ awk '!/^(#|Source)/{sub(/ *$/,"  ")}1' file
```

If you don't care about the latter, you can just add two spaces:

```
$ awk '!/^(#|Source)/{$0=$0 "  "}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to node on your system you can do

```
rexreplace '^((?!#|Source).*)$' '€1  ' file
```

after installing it globally `npm -i rexreplace -g` or run with `npx` prepended